# How to create different page layout for dekstop and defferent layout for salesforce1 app?

Tags: salesforce1-app, page-layout, pagelayoutassignment

I have create a page layout for mobile and different page layout for dekstop.But when I set it on page layout assignment it will affect for the desktop page also. Where can we set one page layout for desktop and one page layout for salesforce1 on the configurations?